# Requested resource address visible on custom login page

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security, oauth-2.0

My simple @Controller requires from requests to some resources to be authenticated.

```
  @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
  @RequestMapping(value = "/confidential**", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public String confidential(Model model) {
    return "confidential";
  }
```

If I am not logged in and try to access /confidential then my custom login page is displayed. This is perfectly fine. I can type my credentials and I will be redirected to confidential page.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(LoginController.ROOT_MAPPING)
public class LoginController {

  @RequestMapping("/login**")
  public String login(HttpServletRequest request, Model model) {
     // model.addAttribute("requestedResource", requestedResource);
  return "login";
  }
}
```

Now I have another requirement. I need to know the requested resource address (like "/confidential") on login() method level. I need this to create redirection_uri for Facebook OAuth2 authentication that my login page has to support.

HttpServletRequest object contains information only about the current request ("/login") and its parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i d'ont know how you can have only the "/confidential" request but with this code, you should have the whole initial url:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(LoginController.ROOT_MAPPING)
public class LoginController {

  @RequestMapping("/login**")
  public String login(HttpServletRequest request, Model model) {
     // model.addAttribute("requestedResource", requestedResource);

  SavedRequest savedRequest = 
    new HttpSessionRequestCache().getRequest(request, response);
  String url = savedRequest.getRedirectUrl();
  // do what you want with url variable and OAuth...

  return "login";
  }
}
```

You should extract the URI, context, servername,... with a regex if you want only a part of the url